# Return result of for loop with iteration

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, return, echo

Well I gave up on trying to get a field from formiddable forms in a current "all" view, in that case I had a field (that contained SCALE01, SCALE02 etc) that would have done the trick but I have no user in the form to hook it on to. And I eventually gave up.

So here I have something that works, the echo is spitting out the answer four times each (there are four entries from fomiddable displaying)like so:

```
<a href="file1">file1<a>
<a href="file2">file2<a>
<a href="file3">file3<a>
<a href="file4">file4<a>
```

(repeated 4 times)

The file links are correct though!

I need to turn that echo into a return so where I put the shortcode from the wordpress function the return gives me the first then the second then the third etc in the right place not at the top of the page. And not four times, just once :)

```
function scale_verification_certificate_func($atts) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $ffield = FrmProEntriesController::get_field_value_shortcode(array(
            'field_id' => 140, 
            'user_id' => 'current'));

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {        
        foreach (glob("./clients/Sites/" . $ffield . "/SCALE0". $i . "/*SCALE_VERIFICATION_CERTIFICATE*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename) {
            echo "<a href='./.$filename.'>.$filename<img src='../document.png' /></a> <br>";
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'scale-verification-certificate', 'scale_verification_certificate_func' );
```

Any help would be appreciated, Im sorry if I didnt write my question very well, its my first one :)

EDIT: I realise why its repeating 4 times now, because their are four folders, that start with that name, but no matter I would still appreciate help on the rest!

Answer (score 0):

Since you figured out the 4x issue, in order for the function to return the string, you could just accumulate the results at each loop, and return a string in the end. Like so:

```
function scale_verification_certificate_func($atts) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $ffield = FrmProEntriesController::get_field_value_shortcode(array(
            'field_id' => 140,
            'user_id' => 'current'));

    $ret_string = "";  // initialize empty string
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        foreach (glob("./clients/Sites/" . $ffield . "/SCALE0". $i . "/*SCALE_VERIFICATION_CERTIFICATE*", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename) {
            // at each loop, append new segment
            $ret_string .= "<a href='./.$filename.'>.$filename<img src='../document.png' /></a> <br>";
        }
    }
    return $ret_string;  // now return the full string
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sal for the quick answer, but this is now returning all four links, albeit in the right place because of the return! But what I need to do is only return 1 link at a time but iterated. so link1 would come up on first instance of the function then link2. My jargon sucks Im sorry! :)

Comment: I don't think you can do that with one single instance of the shortcode. Likely, you'll have to put your shortcode multiple times, each with a parameter, so that the function can generate the code appropriately. Maybe add an example of what your wordpress page should look like (i.e. shortcode(s)) and what you'd like the html output to be.